# How can I package a Windows Air application (with captive runtime) in a single .exe file?

Tags: air

When I compile my Adobe Air 3.4 application (with captive runtime), it produces a folder containing a bunch of stuff (exe, swf, meta-inf, mimetype, etc.). Is it possible to bunch all those files and folders into a single .exe file ? Basically, I want to emulate the way it works on a Mac to make it easy for users to copy and exchange the app.

As you may know, on Mac, a compiled Adobe Air application produces a single .app file. This file is actually a folder but from the user's perspective, it works and looks like a single-file standalone app. I would like to do the same on Windows.

Is that easily feasible ?

P.S. For simplicity's sake, I do not want an installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't specific to AIR, but there appear to be applications out there that will allow you to combine your exe and its assets into a single .exe
In my Googling, I came across
http://www.molebox.com/
and Enigma Virtual Box: http://www.enigmaprotector.com/en/downloads.html

Here's a tutorial on how one fellow packaged his Unity game using Enigma: http://enigmaprotector.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=569

Hope that helps.